# LdapBundle error with symfony 2 version

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using this [`LdapBundle`](https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle).
I have already installed it, but I catch an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension::addSecurityListenerFactory()` in C:\wamp\www\trainingboard\src\IMAG\LdapBundle\IMAGLdapBundle.php on line 41

I know that I have to change my Symfony version to 2.1. I tried to change folder Symfony in vendors, but after that I caught another error. So, I can't so simple change Symfony. Can you give me advice what to do?

P.S. Now I'm using the 2.0.9 version of Symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMAGLdapBundle only works with Symfony 2.0.x

Instead you can try FR3DLdapBundle 1.6.x