# How to modify current user's attributes and persist them through the entire session

Tags: authentication, symfony, service, ldap, symfony-2.1

I'm authenticating my users using IMAG/Ldap-Bundle (BorisMorel/LdapBundle) and I can't persist any changes made to my `User` to my LDAP server. But whenever a user logs in, I need to check some stuff locally and add the user's roles according to some rules.

Whenever imag verifies the user/password on my LDAP server, it'll call a service I created that's listening to the 'bind' event. Here's how it goes:

```
ldap_user_verifier:
    class: MyBundle\Service\LdapUserVerifierService
    arguments: [ @security.context, @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager, @twig ]
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: imag_ldap.security.authentication.pre_bind, method: loadUser }
```

Note: `bind_username_before` is set to `false`, which means `LdapUserVerifierService::loadUser` will only be called after user's logged in and the `User` class is loaded on my `security.context`.

Then I have my `LdapUserVerifierService::loadUser` like this:

```
public function loadUser(LdapUserEvent $event) {

    $ldapUser = $event->getUser();

    [...]

    $ldapUser->setLocalUser($localUser);
    $ldapUser->addRole('ROLE_USER');
    [...]

}
```

That works great, except for that whenever my user changes page (from `/login_check` to `/dashboard`, for example), my modifications to the `security.context.getToken().getUser()` are lost. My user has a `localUser` and `ROLE_USER` associated on `/login_check`, but it doesn't on `/dashboard`.

Because my user is not loaded from my app's database, I can't persist it on the database to be loaded on subsequent pagehits and, therefore, can't persist my object changes without saving on another session variable.

Does anyone know what I'm supposed to handle this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you modify the `SecurityContext`?

Comment: Changes to the event token should be persisted to the security context token, for they both point to the same Token object, I believe. I don't explicitely save the changes to the security_context. I suppose I could call a setToken or something. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Nope. Error remains. I've added a listener to 'kernel.event_listener', and I'm reloading the permissions at every action. This is not an optimal fix (far from it), but I'll keep it like this until I find another way.

Comment: The only thing I can find is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350465/ldapbundle-error-with-symfony-2-version Not sure if still true...have you tried any other bundle by any chance?

Comment: IMAG has been updated to work with 2.1. Anyway, it won't throw any errors, I just lose my modifications when changing pages.

Comment: I might totally be missing the issue here but, when you say "my modifications to the `security.context.getToken().getUser()` are lost", where is the code calling `setToken()`? Because from here: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/security/authorization.html it says you need to call `setToken()` to authenticate the user.

Answer (score -2):

There's just not enough code to provide a better answer, but I don't see where you modify the security.context or the token.

Once you made changes to the user object that you got from the token, you probably need to set this modified user to the token.